# Android Java App crashing upon 3rd image upload every time

Tags: java, android

I have a small application which allows users to upload some basic data (name, student year, level) and then a picture of w/e.
So everything works as expected until a 3rd image is uploaded, and the application restarts and I don't even get an error message.

So i have a main activity which uses a dialog to allow certain data entry and in the dialog data is saved into the main activity. And when the user is done uploading data they can save it all and proceed to the final activity where a list view is presented displaying all the data that has been input.

So the issue is specifically after the second image is uploaded when a user uploads a third image and then proceeds to the final activity it just restarts with out error msg or anything. But if you upload a bunch of stuff with no images you can add and view as much as you want.

So I have a class for my student objects and array adapter and then my activities. I will post all relevant code below.  I have looked into the issue of the array adapter but I dont think it is specifically this since it works fine when there are no images and works till 2 images when they are added. So I really don't understand what the issue is especially since i don't get any error msgs.

Code follows

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView myImage;
    Student myself;
    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList;
    EditText myName;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    static Bitmap img;
    Button finalSave;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.personalImageID);
        myName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        finalSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finalSave);
        myself = new Student();
        studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>(0);
        finalSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                endMainActivity();
            }
        });

    }
    private void endMainActivity()
    {
        Intent studentListIntent =  new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class);
        System.out.println("Main Activity Student List size : " + studentArrayList.size());
        studentListIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("students", studentArrayList);
        startActivity(studentListIntent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myself = new Student();
    }

    public void upload(View view) {
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }


    public void addYearAndLevel(View view) {
        myself.studentName =  myName.getText().toString();
        AddYearAndLevelDialog dialog = new AddYearAndLevelDialog();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(transaction, "fragment");
    }

    public void addToList()
    {
        myself.imageData = img;
        studentArrayList.add(myself);
        System.out.println(myself.studentName + " " + myself.level + " " + myself.year + " " + myself.imageData );
        myName.setText("");
        myself = new Student();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            myImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            img = imageBitmap;
        }
    }

}
```

controller for view

```
public class ReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<Student> students;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
        students = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("students");
        System.out.println("Student List Size : " + students.size());
        list = findViewById(R.id.studentList);
        StudentAdapter adapter = new StudentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), students);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

xml for view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".ReportActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/studentList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Student> students;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View view;

    public StudentAdapter(Context appContext, ArrayList<Student>students)
    {
        this.context = appContext;
        this.students = students;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return students.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return students.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageUploaded);
        TextView studentName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.studName);
        TextView studYearLvl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvlAndYear);
        image.setImageBitmap(students.get(position).imageData);
        studentName.setText(students.get(position).studentName);
        studYearLvl.setText("Level: " + students.get(position).level + "  " + "Year: " + " " + students.get(position).year);

        return view;
    }
}
```

list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageUploaded"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/studName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lvlAndYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. This specific issue was a result of the image size being used for the bitmaps. Reducing the image resolution in the device camera resolved this issue.